# .net core with SPA - websockets controller endpoint not executing

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, single-page-application

I've created a `.net core` controller which, when using postman, I can hit the Get method successfully (validated with breakpoints on the controller constructor and get method) with the URL (https://localhost:44447/api/callsynchronisation/ws)

The code looks like this:

```
public class CallSynchronisationController : ApiControllerBase
{
    private IWebSocketHandler handler;
    public CallSynchronisationController(IWebSocketHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }


    [HttpGet("ws")]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await handler.Handle(Guid.NewGuid(), webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

In my `startup.cs` I've added `app.UseWebSockets()`. This code does execute as expected.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddWebUIServices();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseWebSockets();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();

    // Initialise and seed database
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var initialiser = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContextInitialiser>();
        await initialiser.InitialiseAsync();
        await initialiser.SeedAsync();
    }
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
{
    settings.Path = "/api";
    settings.DocumentPath = "/api/specification.json";
});

app.UseRouting();
```

AddWebUIServices calls onto services.AddControllersWithViews

I've set up websockets in angular with the adress  https://wss://localhost:44447/api/callsynchronisation/ws.

When I try to send a message the connection is still in the connecting state

In chrome the initiating `ws` request never gets a response from the server. I see is the request with a header "upgrade" with the value `websocket` as expected.

The constructor for the controller does not execute (although it does for the previously mentioned `https` get request).

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Sounds like it’s working. What did you expect to see?

Comment: I'd expect to be able to use the websocket - sen messages etc? Currently the websocket isn't connected?

Comment: I'm not sure what your handler code is doing. This code snippet is missing details.

Comment: Does that detail matter? At this point I just want a ws connection to hit a constructor or get method breakpoint. A normal http request does!

Comment: > When I try to send a message the connection is still in the connecting state

What dies this mean. Do you have a screenshot of the browser? Or better yet code and a screenshot of the broswer tools?

Comment: When a client makes a connection using websockets  the initial communication is an  http request which includes an http header "upgrade". This asks the server for a websocket based connection. Until the server performs the upgrade this is known as the connecting state. Messages from the client cannot be sent.

Comment: Calling AcceptWebSocketAsync performs the upgrade

Comment: Yes., its in the code example above! The key issue is that the end point constructor or get method (see above) doesnt get hit at all *unless* I make an https get request to the endpoint!

Comment: I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: The client makes a HTTPS get request to the endpoint above, a break point on the get method will hit. The client makes a websocket connection, the break point won't be hit

Comment: I had an issue with websockets and .NET a while back, does this help at all: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21701#issuecomment-791443818

Comment: Actually, this looks _exactly_ like the issue I had, I was always getting `false` for `HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest`. I would check the order in which you call `UseWebSockets` and `UseEndpoints` in your `Startup` file

Comment: I'm doing the following:

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddWebUIServices();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseWebSockets();

AddWebUIServices calls AddControllersWithViews

Comment: I came back to this today and found that angulars hot reload for ng serve was catching all the wss requests. So now at least the WSS request comes in BUT IsWebSocketRequest is always false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application is a .net core with an angular SPA.

The issue was that I was sending web socket requests to the angular app (ng serve) without appropriate proxy configuration (to route it to the .net core app).

In my case, the ws path happened to match a path in the angular proxy settings which were not ws enabled (hence why non ws requests seemed to be working).

I updated the angular proxy configuration (proxy.conf.js) to proxy web socket requests onto the .net core app as ws requests and all is well!

Here is the detail for others:

```
 {
    context: ["/ws/*"],
    "target": target,
    "secure": false,
    "ws": true
  }
```